# Eloquent ORM optional Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

just a short question, I'm new to Eloquent and the relationships.

I want to keep my database clean so I created a `User`-Model and a `Administrator`-Model.

Now I'm stucked with the relationship... What I wanna do is the following:

On the `users`-table I have an attribute called `account_type`.

If that one is set to `admin` or `administrator` I want to "implement" the `Administrator`-Model to the `User`-Model.

Am I doing a totally wrong approach here or is there a easy "laravel-style" solution for this?

Comment: You could easily use these 2 models with [global scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#global-scopes) - it's missing from the 5.1 docs. Both will reference the same table, but one will get only `account_type='admin'` while the other will get the rest (or rather all of them). Here's how you can implement global scopes in L5 http://softonsofa.com/laravel-5-eloquent-global-scope-how-to/

Comment: Nice feature but not suitable for me, since I want to keep the database clean. So I don't want user AND admin related data in the same table. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class Administrator cannot be implemented in User, because it's not an interface, If you want to use Administrator class, make a relation in User model

```
public function admin()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Administrator');
}
```

then,

```
$users = User::whereHas('admin', function($q) {
    $q->where('account_type', 'administrator'); // or admin
})->get();
```

make `belongsTo` relation in Administrator if you want

reference link: [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)